# Convert a string to uppercase at compile time

Tags: c++, macros, metaprogramming

Is it possible to convert a string to uppercase at compile-time without any size limitation?

Eg.:

```
char* myString = TO_UPPERCASE("a big string here!");
```

Would generate:

```
char* myString = "A BIG STRING HERE!";
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. For what do you need that?

Comment: I'm studying template metaprogramming. Actually I just found out that it's indeed possible with C++ 17. I will post an answer when I manage to do it.

Comment: Note that the type should be `char const[N]`, not `char*`. Or at least `char const*`. Or perhaps a C++11 string literal.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, using [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) and C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/unpack.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/integral_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/value.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/core/to.hpp>

constexpr char to_upper(char c) noexcept
{
    switch(c) {
    default: return c;
    case 'b': return 'B';
    case 'i': return 'I';
    case 'g': return 'G';
    case 's': return 'S';
    case 't': return 'T';
    case 'r': return 'R';
    case 'n': return 'N';
    // The other characters in the alphabet.
    }
}

auto to_upper_str = [](auto hana_str) noexcept {
    return boost::hana::unpack(hana_str, [](auto... chars) noexcept {
        return boost::hana::string_c<
            boost::hana::char_c<to_upper(boost::hana::value(chars))>...>;
    });
};

int main()
{
    auto str = to_upper_str(BOOST_HANA_STRING("Big string."));
    std::cout << boost::hana::to<const char*>(str) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs `BIG STRING.` See on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb8775bcd85f289b).

Comment: it is worth noting that according to [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html#a7f15faa77e126e1c2b08a2224ceefb84) `BOOST_HANA_STRING` can't be used in unevaluated context which makes it less useful in e.g. passing template parameters' values...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you won't try to pass string chain directly to the template and you create helper variable to store this sequence to be further upper_cased you can utilize this code (c++1z):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
struct string_literal_length;

template <std::size_t N>
struct string_literal_length<char const[N]>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = N;
};

template <class STR_T, STR_T &, class = std::make_index_sequence<string_literal_length<STR_T>::value>>
struct string_literal;

template <class STR_T, STR_T &STR, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal<STR_T, STR, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = string_literal_length<STR_T>::value;
    static constexpr char value[string_literal_length<STR_T>::value] = {STR[Is]...};
};

constexpr char str[] = "abc";

template <class SL, class = std::make_index_sequence<SL::size>>
struct string_literal_to_upper;

template <class SL, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal_to_upper<SL, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
    static constexpr char value[SL::size] = { ((SL::value[Is] >= 'a' && SL::value[Is] <= 'z')?(static_cast<char>(SL::value[Is] - 'a' + 'A')):(SL::value[Is]))...};
};

int main() {
    std::cout << string_literal_to_upper<string_literal<decltype(str), str>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> ABC

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MvWLkFITTnWM6yJY)

**Edit:**

To work in VS the code need to be a little bit modified:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T>
struct string_literal_length;

template <std::size_t N>
struct string_literal_length<char const[N]>{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = N;
};

template <class STR_T, STR_T *, class = std::make_index_sequence<string_literal_length<STR_T>::value>>
struct string_literal;

template <class STR_T, STR_T *STR, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal<STR_T, STR, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = string_literal_length<STR_T>::value;
    static constexpr char value[string_literal_length<STR_T>::value] = { (*STR)[Is]...};
};

struct Literal {
   static constexpr char const str[] = "abc";
};

template <class SL, class = std::make_index_sequence<SL::size>>
struct string_literal_to_upper;

template <class SL, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal_to_upper<SL, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
    static constexpr char value[SL::size] = { ((SL::value[Is] >= 'a' && SL::value[Is] <= 'z')?(static_cast<char>(SL::value[Is] - 'a' + 'A')):(SL::value[Is]))...};
};

int main() {
    std::cout << string_literal_to_upper<string_literal<decltype(Literal::str), &Literal::str>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://rextester.com/VGXRQ19396)

Comment: Is it possible to have a constexpr function to declare the helper variable, use the template and then return the variable's `::value`? That way I could write an easy `TO_UPPERCASE()` macro. I've tried it but I'm still not used to the parameter logic.

Comment: Also, in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 I get this error: `Error C2754 'string_literal<STR_T,STR,std::integer_sequence<std::size_t,_Ix...>>': a partial specialization cannot have a dependent non-type template parameter`.